# Using asterisk to hide password fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to place an asterisk every time a user enters a letter in the password field to hide it from others.

Here is the code, without the above implemented, I am just inputing asterisk just to fill the entry place:

```
 <div id="PassWord">
        <div class="PassWord_User">
            <p> Username: <input type="text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="PassWord_Password">
            <p>   Password: <input id="password" name="password" type="text" value="****"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="PassWord_Button">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit"  id="Submit_passwrd" value="Submit Password"/>
            <p id='status'>Status:<Nb_var96></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If there is an article that I can read to do this or example I can follow?  Also, whatever I write, is it going to be a javascript? jQuery? HTML? Something else?

Thank you,
Neil

Comment: Simply use `type="password"` for your text input..

Comment: Google "html password input".

Comment: [No, use jQuery!!!one!!eleven](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use input type as password

```
<input type="password"/>
```

Comment: Thank you all (techfoobar, RacerNerd, Ingo, and Mayank).  All I did was change text to password and it worked.  I thought I was going to have to create a function and do some crazy code!